# Use ajax to load a view, without invoking the action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working through my first MVC project, and struggling with a few things. So far ive been able to load a partial view with ajax using the following line of code

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("New Car User", "Index", "CarUser", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divForms", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

I know that this is loading the partial view attached to the Index action on the Car user controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.CarUsers.ToList());
    }
```

What i want to be able to do is load the view attached to the Create action on the same controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CarUser caruser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CarUsers.Add(caruser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(caruser);
    }
```

but when i use:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("New Car User", "Create", "CarUser", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divForms", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

it basicly just creates a blank row in my table. Can anybody tell me where im going wrong? I think i need to change the action on the controller but im not sure how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Turns out i had two actions called create:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /CarUser/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CarUser caruser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CarUsers.Add(caruser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(caruser);
    }
```

I labelled the first action method as [HttpGet] and changed the @AJAX.ActionLink to HttpMethod = "GET" which has worked